# Three.jsMesh Matrixworld does not update

Tags: javascript, three.js

Good morning, I am trying to orient subpanels on each plane, but seems that using the method that I used to create the mesh(planes) the matrix and matrixWorld does not update. I need to "update" each plane Matrix to be able to translate and rotate the subplanes accordantly. Below I am adding a picture with the steps of geometry generation. I am using BufferGeometry to create the vertices of the panels, and then triangulating them to create the meshes. Below I am including an image with the step-by-step.
Any help would be helpful!

[Step by step - geometry generation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6U0KG.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I figured it out. I built the transformation matrix4 directly from corner vectors. Maybe it can be useful for someone (code below):

```
let vX = new THREE.Vector3(ndes[3][0] - ndes[0][0], ndes[3][1] - ndes[0][1], ndes[3][2] - ndes[0][2]).normalize(),
    vY = new THREE.Vector3(ndes[1][0] - ndes[0][0], ndes[1][1] - ndes[0][1], ndes[1][2] - ndes[0][2]).normalize(),
    vZ = new THREE.Vector3().crossVectors(vX, vY).normalize();

let matrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
matrix.set( vX.x, vY.x, vZ.x, ndes[0][0], 
            vX.y, vY.y, vZ.y, ndes[0][1], 
            vX.z, vY.z, vZ.z, ndes[0][2],
            0,    0,    0,    1);
panels.applyMatrix4( matrix );
```

[paneling surfaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bOWc.jpg)